# Is this Gerund Phrases correct?

Tags: gerunds, gerund-clauses

**Her cleaning the house every day** is not necessary.

So I was wondering, why use **her** instead of **she** in that gerund phrase? Is that actually correct? And can I say "**The maiden cleaning the house everyday** is not necessary" instead of using **her**?

Comment: I am not a English professor, so I do not know the technicalities, but what I do know is that "Her" is correct and not "She," and "The maiden cleaning the house everyday is not necessary" also sounds perfectly fine.

Comment: "Her cleaning the house every day" is a non-finite clause, and such clauses take an accusative subject pronoun like "her", not a nominative one like "she".

Answer (score 2):

> *Her (constantly) cleaning the house every day is not necessary.*

The expression "her cleaning the house every day" is a non-finite clause with a personal pronoun as subject.

Non-finite clauses take an accusative subject pronoun like "her", not a nominative one like "she".

Note that "cleaning" is a verb here, not a noun, as evident from (a) the possibility of it being modified by an adverb like "constantly", but not the adjective form "constant", and (b) the fact that it has a direct object, i.e. "the house".

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting one.

The traditional answer is that *her* is the correct choice - but it is a possessive *her*, not an objective one. So *The maiden's cleaning the house* is the corresponding form.

However, many people don't use the possessive, or only use it in formal speech, so *Her cleaning* and *The maiden cleaning* would be normal for them.

What nobody says (or almost nobody) is *She cleaning the house every day*.

(People would say *She, cleaning the house, found something unexpected*, where "cleaning the house" is a participial clause with adverbial function, but that is a different structure.)

I think the reason that nobody would say "she" is that, however hard grammarians have tried to pretend that Modern English has case inflection on pronouns, it doesn't, except in an artificial "learned" variety.

Joseph Emonds argued in his 1986 paper [*Grammatically Deviant Prestige Constructions*](http://fine.me.uk/Emonds/) that the choice between "subject" and "object" pronouns is structural, not case-based, and this is one kind of example that tends to confirm this: even if some of us have internalised the traditional case distinction, and naturally say *he and I will go* but *between him and me*, we still don't use *I* or *she* in sentences like your example.

Comment: Hold on Colin! Surely, the personal pronouns are inflected for case, e.g. nominative "I", accusative "me", genitive "my/mine" and plain (reflexive) "myself", and so on. Non-finite gerund-participial subject clauses take either genitive or accusative case, hence "her" being the correct form

Comment: Not according to Emonds's argument (originally from Klima). On the one hand there's a "paucity of stimulus" argument, whereby there is not enough evidence in present day English to ground case-marking as a category for a learner, but instead they propose a structural rule where the pronoun takes the marked ("subject") form "if and only if the phrase is an immediate constituent of a sentence (S) which contains an inflected verbal element." I admit that I dont know if there has been more recent work on this.

Comment: That personal pronouns are case-marked is widely accepted by linguists, and I don't see anything to be gained by confusing the OP with arcane theoretical concepts.